# Reading argv[1] gives Segmentation Fault 11 although argc indicates there's two parameters

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, argv, argc

I stumbled upon an issue whereby if I want to read input arguments not inside the `main` method but inside another method into which `argv` is passed by reference I'm getting `Segmentation Fault 11` for reading argument from `argv[1]` that succeeded in the `main` method.

I understand why segmentation fault happens - it's when program tries read outside the memory allocated for it. But here it seems to me I'm doing everything right - reading `argv[1]` is valid in `main` method. Also reading `argv[0]` is valid in the `handleInput` method but for reading `argv[1]` inside `handleInput` method I get `Segmentation fault: 11`. `argc` also indicates there's two parameters but I can only read the first one (the executable filename).

`segfault`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void handleInput(int *argc, char ***argv) {
    printf("%d\n", *argc);
    printf("%s\n", *argv[0]);
    printf("%s\n", *argv[1]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("\n");

    handleInput(&argc, &argv);

    return 0;
}
```

`$ ./segfault parameter`

```
2
./segfault
parameter

2
./segfault
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I'm using `clang` compiler on MacOS

```
$ clang -v
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Why can't I read `argv[1]` inside handleInput method? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OT: You _know_ there will always be a parameter passed... until there isn't... Make it a **habit** to **always** validate incoming data before using it. It's not hard, and you will benefit from not spending hours chasing down hard-to-find bugs. Next year you won't remember that this program or that function required a certain kind of input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to pass pointers to argc and argv, since you're not planning on changing them. Passing by value is fine! Just use them as-is. This should work:

#include <stdio.h>

```
void handleInput(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    printf("\n");

    handleInput(argc, argv);

    return 0;
}
```

I replaced the char **argv with char *argv[] to make it more obvious it is an array of strings.

Comment: And the issue was indeed the precedence - `(*argv)[1]` worked. But I'm going to take your advice and not pass pointers at all. Didn't know you don't have to do that. Thanks! 
FYI: Haven't touched C for work throughout my working career. Just tinkering with it now.

Comment: No problem. Got to be super careful with precedence if you somehow have a char ***! Not something you see most days. Good luck with C, it's quite pleasant once you learn to avoid the pitfalls.